# Error while using TraceSource.TraceEvent in a ASP.NET C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

I found the same question on stack overflow for which I want solution ,but there are no answer to it.

[How to use TraceSource.TraceEvent in a ASP.NET C# web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239541/how-to-use-tracesource-traceevent-in-a-asp-net-c-sharp-web-application)

What is possible mistake I am doing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this post on msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I'am happy to help you vaibhav